# Como actuo dependiendo de la clase

Tags: java

Buenas he estado buscando y no me queda claro:
volvemos  a lo mismo, tengo 2 subclases (Empleado y Cliente) de una super clase Usuario.
como puedo actuar dependiendo del tipo de clase que sea?

```
Usuario usuario
usuario = crearUsuario(); /*devuelve un usuario creado que puede ser de ambos tipos*/
if (usuario.getclass() == <Empleado>) /*funcion*/
if (usuario.getclass() == <Cliente>) ....
```

Se me ocurre algo asi, pero no funciona... !!! Como he de tratarlo? no lo encuentro.

Comment: Deberías de añadir el código que componen el método para poder ayudarte mejor

Answer (score 1):

desconozco como y que hace tu método crearUsuario(), pero prueba de la siguiente forma:

```
Usuario usuario = null;
usuario = crearUsuario(); /*devuelve un usuario creado que puede ser de ambos tipos*/
if (usuario instanceOf Empleado) {
}
if (usuario instanceOf Cliente) {
}
```

Espero que te ayude, deberia funcionar.

Comment: exacto! es el instanceoff gracias!

Comment: Hola @IsmaelGonzalezDominguez, si esta respuesta te sirvió, márcala como aceptada y considera darle un +1.

Answer (score 1):

Como comentan otros usuarios, puedes utilizar el operador `instanceof`.

```
Usuario usuario = crearUsuario();
if (usuario instanceof Empleado) ((Empleado) usuario).metodoEmpleado();
else if (usaurio instanceof Cliente) ((Cliente) usuario).metodoCliente();
```

Pero utilizar `instanceof` dificulta la extensión por herencia, es decir, crear nuevas subclases, ya que tendrás que añadir más código `if else` en cada punto donde compruebes tipos con `instanceof`.

Por ello, también puedes crear un método con implementaciones diferentes en las subclases, siempre y cuando sea razonable.

```
public class Usuario {
    public abstract void metodo();
}

public class Empleado {
    @Override
    public void metodo() {
        // Código que solo el empleado hace
    }
}

public class Cliente{
    @Override
    public void metodo() {
        // Código que solo el cliente hace
    }
}
```

Entonces la llamada no tendría que realizar ningún `instanceof`.

```
Usuario usuario = crearUsuario();
usuario.metodo();
```

Por ligadura dinámica, se llamará al método de la subclase de la que sea el objeto, ya sea cliente o empleado, y al crear nuevas subclases, no hay que tocar nada más del código del programa.

Una última consideración: en muchas situaciones no conviene mezclar usuarios que cumplen roles distintos bajo una sola clase `Usuario`. Si tengo una aplicación en la que algunos usuarios son normales, otros premium, y algunos ultra mega VIP, entonces puedes plantearte crear una jerarquía de usuarios (o crear solo una clase `Usuario` con un atributo `rol`). Sin embargo, cuando son entidades muy diferenciadas, posiblemente no necesites esa jerarquía de usuarios.

Answer (score -2):

```
private void crearUsuario(){
    usuario = interfaz.usuarioNuevo();
    if (usuario instanceof Empleado)
    listaEmpleados.add ((Empleado)usuario);
    if (usuario instanceof Cliente)
    listaClientes.add ((Cliente)usuario);

}
```

Asi quedo!

Comment: Hola Ismael, me alegra que encontraras una solución a tu pregunta. Por favor, añade algo más de detalle para aclarar qué cambios hiciste y cómo resolvieron el problema. Lee [answer] para más información.

Comment: O si acabaste usando una respuesta que sugirió otro usuario (como parece ser el caso), marca la respuesta que te sirvió como aceptada y considera darle un voto positivo. Saludos.